# @media (max-width: not in concordance with set defined value

Tags: html, css

I need help to deal with this issue.

On my CSS is a query required to display

```
@media (max-width:1024px)
{
   .header { display:none; }
}
```

--- COntent goes here ---

My problem is that the queries in this media only reflects when max-width screen is 910px

Also when @media (max-width:800px) changes expected to be made at max-screen width 800px; only appears when screen is 717px

I can't explain what the problem is, but i'd like to know if there is a way to make it responsive to assigned width size?

Remember everything is working perfect, just that it is not in concordance with required value.

Comment: Please add relevant code where we can see your problem.

Comment: What happens at ```1023px``` of screen width with ```.header```?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are adding everything you need in the query.

For example, when I make my media queries for responsive design I do this:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) {
   /* CODE HERE */
}
```

That may fix your problem but please provide more information when asking questions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I realized the problem was caused by my Firefox browser. I tested in other browsers, and everything worked as supposed. It was perfect initially, but suddenly the issues started. And affected even my old projects that was good earlier; that led me into the confusion. However, I will soon upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Happy to see you fixed your problem.